# Simple join from two table mysql in one entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to create an entity in JPA from two tables:

Book

```
+----+------+--------+-------------+
| id | name | author | releaseData |
+----+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | bla  | bla    | 01/01/1970  |
|  2 | bla  | bla    | 01/01/1970  |
|  3 | bla  | bla    | 01/01/1970  |
|  4 | bla  | bla    | 01/01/1970  |
|    |      |        |             |
+----+------+--------+-------------+
```

stock

```
+---------+----------+--+
| book_id | quantity |  |
+---------+----------+--+
|       1 |       10 |  |
|       2 |       12 |  |
|       3 |        5 |  |
|       4 |        9 |  |
|         |          |  |
+---------+----------+--+
```

I would like to create a book entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int    id;
    private String name;
    private String author;
    private Date   releaseDate;

    @JoinTable  
    private Integer   quantity;

}
```

And take the value of quantity from the other table

is this possible?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your entity should be like this:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int    id;
  private String name;
  private String author;
  private Date   releaseDate;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name= "stock_book_id")
  private Stock stock; 
}
```

Then you should add the `StockDTO` class into `BookDTO` like an attribute.